# TCP Congestion Control

Tags: tcp

"End points view congestion as increased delays; therefore, they will aggravate congestion instead of alleviating it."

- Can somebody pls explain this statement to me ?

2nd question: Why does Fast Recovery not recover very well from multiple losses ?

- Here's my understanding of Fast Recovery: Upon reception of three duplicate ACKs, TCP launches a retransmission and then performs Fast Recovery: The congestion window is halved and raised by one segment for each duplicate ACK. So I think this includes the three duplicate ACKs that have started the Fast Retransmit, meaning cwnd_new = cwnd_old + 3 + 1 for every further incoming duplicate ACK. For some reason (why?) after the first non-duplicate ACK arrives at the receiver, cwnd is set to cwnd_old / 2 and then Congestion Avoidance is performed.

Grateful for any help!

Comment: Homework questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can only speculate w/o more context on the precise meaning whoever said that to you had in mind, but here we go.

Retransmissions in TCP (Reno) can be triggered in 2 ways: RTO & DUPACK. RTO is the retransmission timeout - a state reached when there is no ACK for the senders data. DUPACK - duplicate acks sent when the sender misses a packet or they are reordered.

- To your first question: I do not see how TCP is aggrevating congestions, except if this is related to RTO. TCP will congest a network a bit more in the immediate timeframe, when RTO is reached since it will resend unacked segments. However RTO event resets the congestion window to one segment and then slow-start phase begins which should alleviate the congestion after that retransmission.
- To your second question: That is because in ***TCP Reno*** algorithm when multiple losses are encountered it often reaches a state where the only recovery mechanism is a retransmission timeout. How can this happen, see this video for an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6pG9sEVTkg
- `For some reason (why?) after the first non-duplicate ACK arrives at the receiver, cwnd is set to cwnd_old / 2 and then Congestion Avoidance is performed.` when a normal ack is received, the Congestion Avoidance starts, which defines cwnd as `cwnd_old / 2` (the cwnd_old is the one that was reached when durring the time of a timeout or 3xdupacks). This was choosen as a convenient half-way point. You don't want to start at the `cwnd_old` since it gave you problems, you don't want to start at 1, since it's not efficient, so it is quite reasonable to start @ cwnd_old / 2.

Comment: thx very much! The first sentence refers to network congestion without TCP mechanisms to prevent it.. what I still don't understand about fast recovery is: I increase cwnd_old/2  linearly due to incoming DUPACKs. But once the first non-duplicate ACK arrives I decrease it again to cwnd_old/2 . Why would I do that?

Comment: cwnd_old/2 + 1 due to DUP follows one of design principles of TCP -  *conservation* (put 1 packet on network only if 1 is removed). A received DUPACK means that receiver is receiving packets, so you can send 1 packet for each dupack w/o increasing the cwnd (= w/o violating conservation principle).

Comment: Decrease to cwnd_old/2 is because ssthresh (transition point between fast-recovery and congest. avoid. phases) is defined as cwnd_old/2. Think if you could continue doing cwnd_old/2 + 1? No you can't because it is assumed that other packets were sent durring the Fast Recovery and they will get ACKs (those acks will increase cwnd + 1) after the first ACK is received. The value would increase too fast in that case.

Comment: Consider upvoting and accepting if it was helpful.